# Smooth Shading is Not Working

Tags: modeling, smooth

I'm not sure what happened to my scene but the smooth shade option doesn't seem to change much on my objects. The first picture is with smooth shade off and the second is smooth shade on. I'm not sure what option is causing this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Object Data > Normals > Auto Smooth :) ... it just doesn't seems to be that ... even wit Edge Split it wouldn't looks like shaded triangles ... probably some Custom Normals? Eny modifier in use?

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: no modifiers in use. im not sure whats causing it

Comment: i just copied everything to a new blender scene and it all looks fine. something must have messed up with my original sceme